# Python count number or letters on scraped page

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm making requests in Python with `requests`.

I then use `bs4` to select the wanted `div`. I now want to count the length of the text in that div, but the string I get out of it includes all the tags too, for example:

```
<div><a class="some_class">Text here!</a></div>
```

I want to only count the `Text here!`, without all the `div` and `a` tags.

Anyone have any idea how I could do that?

Answer (score 7):

Do you mean:

```
tag.text
```

or

```
tag.string
```

`tag` means the tag that you found use `soup.find()`. Check [the document](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#modifying-string) for more details.

---

Here is a simple demo that helps you understand what I mean:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('<html><body><div><a class="some_class">Text here!</a></div></body></html>', "html.parser")
>>> tag = soup.find('div')
>>> tag
<div><a class="some_class">Text here!</a></div>
>>> tag.string
'Text here!'
>>> tag.text
'Text here!'
>>>
```

---

About *count the length of the text*, do you mean use `len()` here?

```
>>> tag.text
'Text here!'
>>> len(tag.text)
10
```